# MongoDB Query that uses two collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm new to using MongoDB and I'm Stuck in a task of writing query .
My problem statement is that i have two collections

```
maening userId1=>follows userId2
+---------+---------+
| userId1 | userId2 |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 2       |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 3       |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 4       |
+---------+---------+
| 2       | 3       |
+---------+---------+
| 3       | 1       |
+---------+---------+
```

```
second table is as follows
+---------+--------+----------------+
| tweetId | userId | tweetText      |
+---------+--------+----------------+
| ****    | 1      | Tweet By user1 |
+---------+--------+----------------+
| ****    | 2      | Tweet By user2 |
+---------+--------+----------------+
| ****    | 3      | Tweet By user3 |
+---------+--------+----------------+
| ****    | 4      | Tweet By user4 |
+---------+--------+----------------+
```

I want my result to contain all the tweets from users that the user1 follows...?????

Comment: Nawaz did you be able to check my answer? If so please give some feedback whether it worked for you or not.

Comment: Yeah ! thanks ... I'm Implementing this in my program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to design your User and Tweet schemas like this:

User:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  follows: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Tweet:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const tweetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  tweetText: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Tweet", tweetSchema);
```

Then you can use the following code, to insert user, tweet, get user and his followers, and the tweets of the user's followers:

Index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/tweet"; //change url to your db
const User = require("./models/user");
const Tweet = require("./models/tweet");

const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

mongoose
  .connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

app.post("/user", async (req, res) => {
  let result = await User.create(req.body);
  res.send(result);
});

app.get("/user/:userId", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await User.findById(req.params.userId).populate({
    path: "follows",
    select: "_id username"
  });
  res.send(result);
});

app.post("/user/:userId/follow/:followedUserId", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.userId,
    {
      $push: {
        follows: req.params.followedUserId
      }
    },
    { new: true }
  );
  res.send(result);
});

app.post("/tweet", async (req, res) => {
  let result = await Tweet.create(req.body);
  res.send(result);
});

app.get("/user/:userId/followedTweets", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);

  const result = await Tweet.find({ userId: { $in: user.follows } });
  res.send(result);
});
```

First create a few users sending a `POST` to this url `http://localhost:3000/user`:

Request:

```
{
    "username": "username1"
}
```

Then add followers to a given user with this url:

`http://localhost:3000/user/5ddfdfaf8c62b141146cbcff/follow/5ddfdfd18c62b141146cbd02`

This means user with id `5ddfdfaf8c62b141146cbcff` follows user `5ddfdfd18c62b141146cbd02`.

At this point you can get a user and his followed users sending a `GET` request to this url:

`http://localhost:3000/user/5ddfdfaf8c62b141146cbcff`

The response will be like this:

```
{
    "follows": [
        {
            "_id": "5ddfdfbf8c62b141146cbd00",
            "username": "username2"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ddfdfc78c62b141146cbd01",
            "username": "username3"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ddfdfd18c62b141146cbd02",
            "username": "username4"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5ddfdfaf8c62b141146cbcff",
    "username": "username1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

From this response, we understand that username1 follows username2, username3 and username4.

Then you can create tweets sending a `POST` to this url: `http://localhost:3000/tweet`

Request:

```
{
    "userId": "5ddfdfbf8c62b141146cbd00",
    "tweetText": "user 2 tweet 1"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "_id": "5ddfe1e7911cec475093f623",
    "userId": "5ddfdfbf8c62b141146cbd00",
    "tweetText": "user 2 tweet 1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

After adding a few tweet like this you can send a `GET` request this url to get a user's followed user's tweets:

```
http://localhost:3000/user/5ddfdfaf8c62b141146cbcff/followedTweets
```

The response will be like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ddfe1e7911cec475093f623",
        "userId": "5ddfdfbf8c62b141146cbd00",
        "tweetText": "user 2 tweet 1",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ddfe20a911cec475093f624",
        "userId": "5ddfdfbf8c62b141146cbd00",
        "tweetText": "user 2 tweet 2",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ddfe22b911cec475093f625",
        "userId": "5ddfdfc78c62b141146cbd01",
        "tweetText": "user 3 tweet 1",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: everything is working properly except the last query that shows an array of tweets by other person that the user follows. even after following and adding tweets for other users i'm getting an empty  array as a result

Comment: @NawazMoinyaakuza are you sure you are using correct userIds? Because  I tested this code.

Comment: @NawazMoinyaakuza did you create tweets from users which your user follows?

Comment: `router.route('/:userId/followedTweets').get((req,res)=>{
    const user=User.findById(req.params.userId);
    Tweet.find({userId:{$in:user.follows}})
    .then(followersData=>res.json(followersData))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json("Error:"+err))
})`

Comment: @NawazMoinyaakuza be sure you create documents correctly, did you create tweets for users?

Comment: can u please also help me to find the followers of any particular user??

Comment: @NawazMoinyaakuza in my answer, there is info which users a user follows. Using that example, try to do this by yourself, if you can’t and I find time I will try to help. But for learning best, you need to try,

Comment: I am trying to write a query to find out a list a of user that a particular user is not following (i.e a list of users that are not present in user.follows). Can u help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

you can use the aggregation to achieve your specific result.
Like you have 2 collections, first_collection and second_colleciton.

```
db.getCollection('first_collecition').aggregate([
{
        "$facet":{
            "tweets":[
                "$lookup":{
                    "from":"second_collection",
                    "localField":"userId1",
                    "foreignField":"userId",
                    "as":"tweets"
                },
                {
                    "$project":{
                        "userId":"$userId",
                        "tweets":"tweetText"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

])
```